# What is a homogeneous curve or a circle?

Tags: calculus, integration, line-integrals

I am facing a problem which asks to find coordinates of mass center of a **homogeneous curve L**. Obviously, this should be done by the line integral but the part I do not understand at all is the **homogeneous curve**? What does it mean?

Alternatively, there comes another problem which asks coordinates of **a homogeneous circle**

Thank you for help.

P.s. I cannot find anything about this online neither in English or in my native language

Comment: The meaning of the word "homogeneous" depends on the context. For example, there are homogeneous polynomials of several variables. In this context, we are finding center of **mass**. That implies there is mass distribution and we are told it is a homogeneous one. In general, the mass could vary in density along a curve, but we are told it doesn't.

Comment: @piromenas  Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Homogeneous curve means that we can assume the linear mass constant along the curve, that is

$$dm=\rho ds$$

with $\rho$ (kg/m) constant.

Since the value of $\rho$ doesn't affect the position of the center of mass we can assume $\rho=1$ and thus evaluate the line integral neglecting any information on the mass.

Comment: Does not the **homogeneous** also have something with γ function of the mass? Because in the problem I have to figure out, there is no mass function given, while in order to calculate the mass you have to have the mass function

Comment: indeed we can assume $\rho=1$ in order to find the center of mass and thus $dm=ds$

Comment: @piromenas: the mass function is said to be constant and the exact value does not matter for centroid computation. So you take $\rho$.

Answer (score 0):

For an homogeneous circle, by symmetry, the mass center must be the geometric center.

For an arbitrary curve, you will obtain the average $x$ and average $y$ by integration of $ds, x\,ds$ and $y\,ds$. The constant linear mass cancels out.